# How do I reduce the panels font size in PyCharm?

Tags: fonts, pycharm

I accidentally set the font size way too big in PyCharm, and now I am unable to go back to normal because I don't see anything.

[image: screenshot of PyCharm with oversized fonts]

Comment: If you press `ctrl` + `alt` + `s`, can you navigate the settings dialog?

Comment: Refer this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-code-editor.html#46a4463c

Answer (score 0):

You can press `Ctrl+Alt+S` to open the Appearance & Behavior tab to change your font size.

Comment: Yes, but as soon as I do that, i'm also unable to what is going on on that menu, because of the size.

Comment: First press CTRL + SHIFT + A  then in the popup frame start typing  Increase font size or Decrease font size, and press  ENTER  as soon as the corresponding command gets the focus, then the font will grow larger or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing the configuration file outside of PyCharm and then reloading it.

In file explorer navigate to:

```
C:\Users\userid\.Pycharm.xx\config\options\ui.Inf.xml
```

The contents should look something like:

```
<application>
  <component name="UISettings">
    <option name="FONT_SIZE" value="20" />
    <option name="OVERRIDE_NONIDEA_LAF_FONTS" value="true" />
  </component>
</application>
```

Here you can lower the font size, or change the `OVERRIDE_NONIDEA_LAF_FONTS` to `"false"`

Save and reload PyCharm.